# Generalization of L'Hospital's rule

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions at $(a,b)$ where $-\infty\leqslant a<b\leqslant +\infty$. Also $f(x),g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a$ or $f(x),g(x)\to \pm \infty$ as $x\to a$ and exists $\lim \limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$. Then $$\lim \limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim \limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$ It's from baby Rudin (theorem 5.13).

Let's take a look at these examples $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{x^k}{e^x}$ and after taking first derivatives we get expressions which is also is indeterminacy $\frac{0}{0}$ and $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. I think that in this case L'Hospital's rule must be modified. Can anyone write how this modification looks?

Comment: I don't think we need to modify. If l'Hopital's rule works after a certain number of iterations, we can then retroactively fill in the limits for each step with the standard rule.

Comment: @MichaelBiro, Dear! You think that above theorem can be used in above examples? But after taking first derivatives we get  indeterminacy. But theorem says that limit $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ must exists (finite or infinite).

Comment: Sure, but then use the theorem on $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$, and repeat as necessary...

Comment: @MichaelBiro, maybe you want to write use the theorem on $\lim \limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f^{(k)}}{g^{(k)}}$?

Comment: Well, you get there eventually. $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ if the second limit exists. $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f''(x)}{g''(x)}$ if the second limit exits, and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f''(x)}{g''(x)} = \lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f'''(x)}{g'''(x)}$ if the second limit exists, etc. If l'Hopital's rule works after $k$ iterations, you get that each   limit exists and is equal.

Comment: @MichaelBiro, Thanks a lot for such clear answer! I understood that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f^{(k)}}{g^{(k)}}$$ exists and $f^{(k-1})$, $g^{(k-1)}\to 0$ or $\pm\infty$, then the theorem guarantees that $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f^{(k-1)}}{g^{(k-1)}}$$ exists and is equal. Then, if $f^{(k-2})$, $g^{(k-2)}\to 0$ or $\pm\infty$,  $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f^{(k-2)}}{g^{(k-2)}}$$ exists and is equal. Etc.

Comment: Dear Martin! Thank you very much for such clear answer.

Comment: You also need $f^{(j)}(x) = g^{(j)}(x) = 0$ for $j < k$.

Comment: @martycohen: Good point. Edited.

Comment: Actually, also if both $= \infty$. I'll get it right eventually (or I won't:)